# Process Still running in background after python script converted to exe with pytoexeconverter

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way properly kill a process once the application exits? If yes how can I integrate this in my python script so that it does the job automatically if it exits? I got this code to restart my app when it craches but since the process is still running in the backgroung it doesn't work. Cheers

```py
proccess = 'app'
def checkIfProcessRunning(process):
    '''
    Check if there is any running process that contains the given name processName.
    '''
    #Iterate over the all the running process
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # Check if process name contains the given name string.
            if process.lower() in proc.name().lower():
                return True
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return False

def ex():
    os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM Trailling.exe')

#atexit.register(ex)

def start_process():
    return os.system(cmd)
try:
    start_process()
    atexit.register(ex)
    while True:

        if checkIfProcessRunning('process'):
            print("Process is running")
            time.sleep(5)

        else:
            print("Process is not running")
            start_process()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At any exit point for your program, simply add a function to kill the process. You're already checking if the process is running, and you can use the same interface to kill the process.

I would recommend modifying `checkIfProcessRunning` to, instead of returning `True` or `False`, return the process if it exists, or return `None` otherwise:

```
def checkIfProcessRunning(process):
    '''
    Check if there is any running process that contains the given name processName.
    '''
    #Iterate over the all the running process
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # Check if process name contains the given name string.
            if process.lower() in proc.name().lower():
                return proc
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return None
```

This should still work with your `if` checks (by default, any non-`None` object registers as truthy), and it makes it much easier to build a kill method, using the process's `.kill()` method:

```
def killProcessIfRunning(process):
    '''
    Kill the process, if it's running.
    '''
    proc = checkIfProcessRunning(process)
    if proc:
        proc.kill()
        # alternatively, use proc.terminate() if you want to be more hardcore and are not on Windows
        # or proc.send_signal() with SIGSTOP or something
```

Then, just call the kill method at any exit point for your program (since you've used `atexit`, this should just be the `ex()` method regardless):

```
def ex():
    killProcessIfRunning('process')  # replace with the name of the same process you started with
    os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM Trailling.exe')
```

Comment: So I did what you suggested, called the kill method at the program's exit point and it worked. However when I use the original part of the code to start my program and check if it running in spyder, it opens the exe file of the program and once it exits it still tells me that the process is running. In task manager when it run this script I have Windows Command Processor

Comment: that is deployable > C:\Windowns\system32\cmd.exe, Console Windows Host, Raiseexception, Raiseexception (the name of the app used for testing your code, twice). And when the program exits the script tells me that "the program is still running" even though it exited and I cant see any running Windows Command Processor that is deployable in which I can see Raiseexception.

Comment: here is how the original script looks like now: import time
import sys
import psutil
import os
import atexit
import subprocess
app = 'Raiseexception'
cmd = r"C:\Users\g\Desktop\API\Raiseexception.exe"

Comment: def checkIfProcessRunning(app):
    '''
    Check if there is any running process that contains the given name processName.
    '''
    #Iterate over the all the running process
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # Check if process name contains the given name string.
            if app.lower() in proc.name().lower():
                return True
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return False

Comment: def ex():
    os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM Raiseexception.exe')

#atexit.register(ex)

def start_process():
    return os.system(cmd)
    #or
    #process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=0x08000000)
    #process.wait() #the subprocess doesn't work for me

Comment: try:
    start_process()
    atexit.register(ex)
    while True:

        if checkIfProcessRunning('app'):
            print("Process is running")
            time.sleep(5)

        else:
            print("Process is not running")
            start_process()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

Comment: I think that just os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM Trailling.exe') kills the process and flushes threads by itself

Answer (score 0):

The good news about the error that I commented about in my previous answer is that when you put a working app in the right folder and take out the double '' is that the restart script works and it restarts the program indefinitely with the following script:

```
import time
import psutil
import os
app = 'Raiseexception'
cmd = r"C:\Users\g\Desktop\API\Raiseexception.exe"
def checkIfProcessRunning(app):
    '''
    Check if there is any running process that contains the given name processName.
    '''
    #Iterate over the all the running process
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # Check if process name contains the given name string.
            if app.lower() in proc.name().lower():
                return True
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return False

def ex():
    os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM Raiseexception.exe')


def start_process():
    return os.startfile(cmd)

try:
    start_process()
    while True:

        if checkIfProcessRunning(app): #check for double ' '
            print("Process is running")
            time.sleep(5)

        else:
            print("Process is not running")
            start_process()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Cheers,

Lrd